# Original FuelPHP Auth Driver

Tags: php, abstract-class, fuelphp

I'm creating original Auth_Login_MyDriver extending Auth_Login_Driver.
I implemented login method like this.

```
public function login($email,$pass){
}
```

But I got the following error.

```
Declaration of Auth\Auth_Login_Mydriver::login() must be compatible with Auth\Auth_Login_Driver::login()
```

I understand the reason. I must declare login().

But the SimpleAuth package declared like following.

```
public function login($username_or_email = '', $password = ''){}
```

How do I declare login method with parameters?

FuelPHP: 1.7.3
PHP: 5.6.13

Comment: How about spelling "function" correctly?

Comment: Raptor, thanks I fixed.

Comment: I'll look into it, but can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to achieve? If your approach is impossible, we may be able to help with an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give you two answers, one answers the case you only want the parameters to be `$email`, and `$password`. The other tells, how to create a login method with different parameters, since the same error would raise if you want to achieve that. (And at first I wasn't sure what your problem was).

### Your problem:

Your problem is that the two signatures are incompatible. This is because you didn't provide default values for the parameters in the `login` function. You can solve it simply replacing

```
function login($email, $password)
```

with

```
function login($email = '', $password = '')
```

Other causes of this error could be that your typehints differ with the parent's. For example:

```
function login(LoginParams $loginParams)
```

but you just try to override it with:

```
function login($loginParams)
```

### To have different parameters:

Ok, you have two options.

First:
You don't extend `Auth\Auth_Login_Driver`. This means you have to implement all the necessary functions of `Auth\Auth_Login_Driver`. Obviously if you need a very similar functionality, most of your code is going to be some duplication, which should be avoided.

Second:
You don't name your function `login`. This means that your class will still expose a `login($username, $password)` function, which most probably you don't want to be usable. In your place, I'd just throw a `RuntimeException` in `login`. Then you can just declare another function like this:

```
function login_with_third_param($username = '', $password = '', $third_param = '') {
}
```

When using this driver, you can just say:

```
Auth::login_with_third_param('joe', 'secret', 'spoon');
```

It'll work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I need default values.

Answer (score 0):

if u using create controller auth.php, login method declaration like this. 
your method must be `action_login($email=null,$pass=null){}`

```
class Controller_Auth extends \Controller_Template
{

       function action_login($email=null,$pass=null)
            {}
}
```

[image: see below]

Comment: Thanks your answer. But I am creating a Driver extending Auth_Login_Driver.

Comment: what is your namespace in auth.php ?

Comment: Now I'm test in Task. So, the namespace is Fuel\Tasks

Comment: is task.php in inside of classes/controller?

Comment: No, my program is fuel/app/tasks/test_auth.php.

Comment: i think this good create in fuel/app/classes/controller then i can help you. i'm not sure tasks works in my method. i think your problem in namespace or extends.

Comment: Sorry @ashan_SL, but you don't seem to understand the question. It has nothing to do with namespaces. It's about a restriction in the auth driver API.

Comment: It's a language restriction. In PHP you cannot have a function with the same name as in the parent, but with a different signature. So if you alter the parameters (number of parameters, or the typehints of them), you get this error.